# Understanding the raft algorithm RequestVote RPC

Tags: python, distributed-computing, raft

I'm trying to read page 4 of this paper: https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf

I am trying to implement the RequestVote RPC but I'm struggling to understand the second part of the "receiver implementation." "If votedFor is null" makes sense! However, the second part where it says "or candidateId and candidate's log is at least up-to-date as receiver's log, grant vote."

I feel like my interpretation below is mistaken.

class LogEntry:
term: int
command: Command

log: list[LogEntry] = []

class RequestVote:
term: int
candidateId: str
lastLogIndex: int
lastLogTerm: int

def on_request_vote_recieved(vote: RequestVote) -> None:
if not votedFor:
send(success)
elif log[vote.lastLogIndex].term >= lastLogTerm:
send(success)
else
send_failure()

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> Raft determines which of two logs is more up-to-date by comparing the
> index and term of the last entries in the logs. If the logs have last
> entries with different terms, then the log with the later term is more
> up-to-date. If the logs end with the same term, then whichever log is
> longer is more up-to-date.

you code misses a check, it should have three checks:

1. if not yet voted in given term (you have that)
2. check if term is larger (you have this, well part of it in >=)
3. if terms are the same, then you have to compare the length of log (this is the missing part; basically the elif should be split into two)

p.s.
I assume send(success) also updates this follower's votedFor value for the given term, and there is code which resets votedFor if a larger term is available